# Null Pointer with Spring @Autowired

Tags: spring, hibernate, pointers, null, autowired

I am new to Spring & Hibernate and I have spent a couple of weeks trying to get to grips with it. Most of my experience is with Oracle development so this is a departure for me. Hibernate is working but Spring is giving me a headache.

I tried following this tutorial but using an Oracle db and my Address table.

http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-4-and-hibernate-4-integration-tutorial-part-1-xml-configuration

The web page wasn't working  so I tried a test case on the HomeController.java That didn't work so but I believe I have narrowed it down to a null pointer in addressDao and so I wrote a test case for that to try to pin it down.

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
     springexp.unittest.AddressDaoTest.testListAddr(AddressDaoTest.java:29)

```
package springexp.unittest;

import bussys.model.Address;
import springexp.dao.AddressDao;
import java.util.List;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

public class AddressDaoTest
{
  @Autowired
  private AddressDao addressDao;

  @RequestMapping(value="/")
  /**
   * @see springexp.dao.AddressDao#listAddr()
   */
  @Test
 public void testListAddr()
 {
    List<Address> listAddresses = addressDao.listAddr();  << error thrown here
    System.out.println(listAddresses.get(1).getFirstname());

    fail("Unimplemented");
  }
}
```

I have also spent a long time reading stackoverflow and others to try to fix the null pointer issue but there seems to be lots of ways of writing this and it has changed in various versions.

In servlet-context.xml I have this:

```
 <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
  <bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
          <value>springexp.dao.AddressDao</value>
        </list>
      </property>
  </bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven />
  <bean id="transactionManager"
     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="addressDao" class="springexp.dao.AddressDaoImpl">
      <constructor-arg>
          <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
      </constructor-arg>
  </bean>

  <!-- added this recently based on one suggestion -->
  <bean id="addressDaoTest" class="springexp.unittest.AddressDaoTest">
      <constructor-arg>
          <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
      </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
```

AddressDaoImpl.java

```
 package springexp.dao;
    import bussys.model.Address;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.hibernate.Criteria;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    public class AddressDaoImpl
      implements AddressDao
    {
      private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

      public AddressDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory)

      {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
      }

      @Override
      @Transactional
      public List<Address> listAddr()
      {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

        List<Address> listAddress = (List<Address>)
             sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Address.class).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
        return listAddress;
      }
    }
```

I hope this is enough to give a clue to my mistake(s).

Comment: `"error thrown here"` it always means that the error is not inside `AddressDaoImpl` this can only happen if your `addressDao` is null. In Spring`"@Autowired"` is equal to `"@Autowired(require=true)"` and always guarantees that `addressDao` is injected so it can't be null. Otherwise Spring would throw exception during initialization. Therefore you are not using Spring dependency injection here. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194204/junit-test-null-pointer-exception  - there are a lot of duplicate quiestions on this topic.

Comment: That is what I am asking, why has @Autowire not worked ?  I have tried many of the suggestions you refer to without result which is why I am here.

Comment: Did you see the answer? You need to add `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file://..somepathto../servlet-context.xml /or classpath://... " })` to your test - so that JUnit will use Spring - otherwise Spring is not used and your test is just a class with JUnit annotations.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried something similar a few days ago but your suggestion has worked better:

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/webapp/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml" })
public class AddressDaoTest
</code>

This has made some progress but I think there is something else amiss because I now get this error:
Line 10 in XML document from URL [file:src/webapp/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 2; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

Comment: Are you able to deploy your application as a war file? Does it print into log that it has successfully initialized the context?

Comment: At this moment we don't have a Weblogic server (WLS) set-up so initially  I ran a jsp web page from Jdeveloper using the integrated WLS but that returned nothing so I created the test case to try to simplify things and ran into the null pointer error. I am now investigating the error above.

Comment: I added more locations and that has moved the issue on.
<beans...
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"
...>

Comment: After a lot of work I got this unit test working. Amongst other changes I added    <property name="packagesToScan" value="bussys.model" />    to servlet-context.xml  
Many thanks. Now I have to wire-up the jsp !